# Display data same time after nested http.request AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, model-view-controller

I have a question regaarding multiple http requests that are nested like this:

```
  $http({
    method: 'jsonp',
    url: 'URL1',
  }).then(function (response) {
    // Response result 1
    // nested http request --> after first http success
    $http({
       method: 'jsonp',
       url: 'URL2'
    }).then(function (response) {
      // Response result 2

    }, function Error(response) {
      $scope.users = response.statusText;

    }).finally(function () {
      $scope.loading = false;

    });
  });
};
```

Is there any way to show both results on the view at the same time? When I add `$scope.data.length` to determine to show a button `if length is > 1`, the button comes before any data. I want to show data from both success at same time in view. Is this possible?

I've read about `$q`, but will this work here and render view on same time both result data is available?

PS: I know it's bad practice to add `http` requests in controller, but this is just to test.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use promise chaining. Also use catch method, it should improve code readability.

```
$http({ method: 'jsonp', url: 'URL1'})
   .then(function (firstResult) {
     //save firstResult
     return $http({ method: 'jsonp', url: 'URL2'})
   })
   // this then will be called only if first one succeeds
   .then(function (secondResult) {
    //save secondResult - display data if this is available
   })
   .catch(function Error(response) {
      // catch errors form both requests
      $scope.users = response.statusText;
   })
   .finally(function () {
      $scope.loading = false;
   })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have to user $q like this :

```js
$q.all([$http({ method: 'jsonp', url: 'URL1'}).$promise, $http({ method: 'jsonp', url: 'URL2'}).$promise]).then(callBackSuccess, callBackError);

function callBackSuccess(results){
var firstResult = results[0];
// do what do you want from firstResult
var secondResult = results[1];
// do what do you want from secondResult
}
```